# Master-detail view which is not initial in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, master-detail

I'm new to Swift.

I want to build a Master-detail view which is not initial of the app. The AppDelegate.swift generated by Xcode using Master-detail Application just go crash when I set other view before the Master-detail view.

Here's the code of AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
        let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
        let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        return true
    }
```

And I got the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x11079e418) to 'UISplitViewController' (0x1107a8eb8).
(lldb)
```

And my Main.storyboard:

[image: Main.storyboard]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial view controller is a `UIViewController` but in the beginning of `application(application:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`  you are still acting as though the first view onscreen is a `UISplitViewController` (see `let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController`
).

In order to have a different view be the initial view controller you need to update that code appropriately to handle the different view controller being first.

Comment: Yes I know why it caused but I just don't know how to update... :(

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. I would suggest start by commenting it all out. Then when things don't work further in the app you can research those specific issues and ask targeted questions when you get stuck. It sounds a little like you are just starting out and trying to jump into the deep end a little quick. Until you understand what the code you pasted in does don't try to get too clever.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, since you are trying to cast a `UIViewController` to a `UISplitViewController` in this line:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
```

You either have to set the split as your initial view controller, or change the code and handle the root as a normal UIViewController.

Comment: Yes I know why it caused but I just don't know how to change the code... :(

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can delete the entire code from the `application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` method and leave only `return true` and the app should work fine and load your initial view controller

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I think the answer is that if you are intending to start the storyboard with a View Controller rather than the Split View Controller then the initial template selected for setting up the project should be Single View application rather than Master-Detail application.